# BPCS STEGANOGRAPHY

Tags: matlab, embedding, steganography

i am  doing BPCS STEGANOGRAPHY.. i have separate secret blocks (4096- 8*8 blocks) and conjugation block( 64 - 8*8 blocks) ready for embedding. each can be accessed separately by calling

```
secret_block(:,:,1),
secret_block(:,:,2),
secret_block(:,:,3)
```

etc and

```
conju_block(:,:,1),
conju_block(:,:,2),
conju_block(:,:,3)
```

etc

During bpcs embedding cover image is bitplane sliced and stored as `c1( lsb plane ),c2,c3,c4 c5,c6,c7,c8` (msbplane). I need to select lsb bit plane to msb plane and  dividing each bitplane into 8*8 block, `selected_block(:,:,i))` and among them complex blocks are replaced with initially `secret_block (:,:,i)` and later on `conju_block(:,:,i)` etc until all the 4096+64 blocks reached..

Please anyone tell me how replace on particular block of `selected_block(:,:,i)` with another block `(conju_block(:,:,i) or secret_block(:,:,i))` ? Is it possible to use `replace_block()` for the same ,then what does 'sys' parameter means ????

Answer (score 0):

I would start by putting all bit planes in one cell,

```
C{1} = c1;
C{2} = c2;
etc
```

so you can go through the bit planes in an automated manner.

```
for i = 1:8
    curr_plane = C{i};
end
```

There are many ways to split a 2D array into blocks. A convenient one is `mat2cell`. The [web documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) gives you a visual example of how it works.

Note that since you want 8x8 blocks, both the rows and columns must be exactly divisible by 8. You have 3 options:

- only allow images with number of rows and columns divisible by 8,
- automatically rescale images to such a size, or
- take the biggest slice of the image matrix with such a size, do your steganography and put that modified image back into your slice of the original image, from where it came from.

We continue with the assumption that you have an image with number of rows and columns divisible by 8. Let's call your initial cover image `cover`.

```
row = size(cover, 1)/8;
col = size(cover, 2)/8;
blocks = mat2cell(curr_plane, ones(1, row)*8, ones(1, col)*8);
```

`blocks` is now a cell which holds all the 8x8 blocks of your bit plane, `curr_plane`. For example, if your bit plane had a size of 16x48, you now have 2x6 blocks. You can iterate through them simply with

```
for bi = 1:size(blocks,1)
    for bj = 1:size(blocks,2)
        my_8x8_block = blocks{bi,bj};
    end
end
```

You're almost there. To sum up what we've done, we go from bit plane to bit plane and split each one in 8x8 blocks. Now, for every `my_8x8_block`, you can feed it into a function which calculates whether it's complex enough or not. If it is, you can simply overwrite it with the kth secret or conjugate block.

```
blocks{bi,bj} = secret_block(:,:,k);
```

Finally, once you have gone through a whole bit plane, you can put back the blocks to construct the modified bit plane

```
C{i} = cell2mat(blocks);
```